# AWS Java SDK Build Error

Tags: aws-java-sdk

I am trying to build the `AWS` SDK for java. I have followed the steps as specified on the github repository. I'm getting the following error when i run

```
mvn clean install


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
19.1:test (default-test) on project aws-java-sdk-core: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\<USER>\Downloads\aws-sdk-java-master\aws-java
-sdk-core\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :aws-java-sdk-core
```

any suggestion on how to build the sdk and use it in my java project.

[EDIT]

[image]

[EDIT 2]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xsDV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the maven output it seems like there are test failures in the `aws-java-sdk-core` package. To save you scrolling back through the maven output to figure out what tests have failed you can have the surefire-plugin generate an HTML report for you. Just run

`mvn clean install surefire-report:report`

it should spit out a report to `target/site/surefire-report.html`

Comment: i have edited the OP to include the screenshot of surefire report.html plz suggest

Comment: i can see some socket closed errors in the console window if that helps

Comment: Do the socket closed errors occur during a test execution? Which test? Can you share the detail.

Comment: i have updated the op - anywhere i can get the pre-compiled sdk?

Comment: The compiled SDK is vended via Maven (see here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk) you can also download a zip directly : https://sdk-for-java.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-java-sdk.zip